# Reducing memory footprint of running large seed.exs

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a large seed file that I'm trying to run on my cheap server.  It is the full list of hs tariff codes, 4000+ items with large text fields. The seed file is 1.1mb

I'm saving the tariff maps to a tariffs variable, then doing this:

```
tariffs
  |> Enum.each(fn(tariff)->
    hs_tariff = struct(Myapp.Tariff, tariff)
    Myapp.Repo.insert!(hs_tariff)
  end)
```

This works fine to insert all the rows on my 8gb ram dev computer, but I get a "stack smashing detected error" on my 512mb ram server.  Short of breaking this into lots of different files, how can I reduce the memory use to actually seed this on my server? Would it make a difference to stream this instead of Enuming it?

Comment: Are you sure Ecto is a problem? What's the size of only the loaded `tariffs` maps? Maybe you can load it lazily instead of all at once - in this case Streams could be really convenient to use.

Comment: I'll try to enum only 10, and see if it works.  That should tell me if the overflow is happening when the maps are loaded into memory or when the writes happen

Comment: Ok, I tried this with stream, enum take, enum chunk.  I keep getting the stack smashing error.  Can it be that just saving the list to the tariff variable is causing this?

Comment: do you have the seed file available publicly with a gist of your code? I have imported large csv files without issues.

Comment: Here's the seed file: https://gist.github.com/Dania02525/12b9519858abef45d39a beware, might crash your browser copying it.  I ended up just doing a pg_dump and loading it direct into postgres which worked out OK.